# how to compare the object from two different array list?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

The program I am writing is an auction application and what I have done so far is that two constructors create two `ArrayList` which are a *painting* and a *bid* list. The `Painting` list includes the painting *ID* and its *name*. The `Bid` list, instead, includes the *painting* names and the bid amount for each one.

What I actually need is to prompt a message after which the user has to introduce its *username*, showing the painting name and the highest bid for it at the moment. For example, the highest amount for the *Strawberries* painting is *1000000*. So far, I have managed to show the painting name but not the highest bid.

I would really appreciate if you could help me getting and idea of where to start from this point. It has been two days and I still cannot figure out the solution to my problem. Below are some blocks of code:

**ArrayList constructor for  *Painting***

```
private ArrayList<Painting> Painting;        
    {
        Painting = new ArrayList<Painting>();
    }

    public void add(int id, String name,String artist,String minibidprice)
    {
        Painting.add (new Painting(id,name,artist,minibidprice));
    }
    public void listAll ()
    {
        for (Painting p : Painting)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

**ArrayList constructor for bid list**

```
    private ArrayList<Bids>Bids;
    {
        Bids = new ArrayList<Bids>();
    }


    public void add(int id, String bname,String pname,int value)
    {
        Bids.add (new Bids(id,bname,pname,value));
    }
     public void listAll2 ()
    {
        for (Bids b : Bids)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
```

Below are the elements for these `ArrayList` objects. The first ones are the paintings, and the next ones the bids.

```
Bidlists p = new Bidlists();
p.add(1440,"Water-Lillies","Claude Monet","$10,000.00");
p.add(1441,"Flowers in a Blue Vase ","Paul Cezanne","$20,000.00");
p.add(1442,"The Anglers","Henri Rousseau ","$50,000.00");
p.add(1443,"Wild Potato Dreaming","Emily Kngwarreye","$45,000.00");
p.add(1446,"Argenteuil","Claude Monet ","$100,000.00");
p.add(1447,"Luncheon on the Grass","Paul Cezanne","$50,000.00");
p.add(1448,"Antonia","Amadeo Modigliani ","$30,000.00");
p.add(1450,"The Young Apprentice","Amadeo Modigliani","$20,000.00");
p.add(1451,"Woman with Mandolin","Henri Matisse","$15,000.00");
p.add(1457,"Strawberries","Pierre-Auguste Renoir $","$30,000.00");
p.add(1458,"Alhalker Suite","Emily Kngwarreye ","$40,000.00");

Bid lists bid = new Bid lists();
bid.add(1,"Bill Chivers","Wild Potato Dreaming",100000000);
bid.add(2,"Ric Herbert","Strawberries",11000000);
bid.add(2,"Simon","Strawberries",32500000);
bid.add(4,"Bill Chivers","Luncheon on the Grass",90000000);
bid.add(5,"Simon ","Wild Potato Dreaming",110000000);
bid.add(6,"Bill Chivers ","Strawberries",25000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use a `Map` for this, as it is designed to allow some data to be associated with (i.e. looked up by) a given key.  In this case, you would Map from the painting ID to the highest bid (or alternatively to the list of all bids, which you maintain in sorted order and so can easily select the highest).

If you must use lists for some reason, then you can still implement your requirement by iterating over the list of bids, inspecting each element in turn.  When you find a bid that relates to your painting ID, then you can consider it, else ignore bids for other paintings.  Note however that this is less efficient in terms of execution speed, and also involves more manual code (so is more error prone), compared to using a `Map`.

In terms of picking the highest bid, it would help a **lot** if you gave your `Bid` class a "natural ordering" (based on the bid size).  This can be done by implementing `Comparable` - and once this has been done, the collections framework can handle the sorting implementation for you.  You will, however, have to actually store the price as a number rather than as a String.  This is a good idea anyway, since Strings are completely opaque otherwise.

A quick example:

```
// Make Bids comparable
public class Bid implements Comparable<Bid> {
    // fields as before, though we change the amount:
    private final BigDecimal amount;

    // Constructor as before - except you'll need to change the class of the amount

    // now we add the compareTo method
    public int compareTo(Bid other) {
        // This says that Bids are ordered in the opposite way that their amounts
        // are ordered, i.e. highest first
        return -amount.compareTo(other.amount);
    }
}

// Now in your main class you'll need to store the bids for each painting, rather
// than just a list:
private Map<Integer, List<Bid>> bidsByPainting = new HashMap<>();

// Change the method that adds bids so it looks a bit like this:
void add(Bid bid) {
    List<Bid> existing = bidsByPainting.get(bid.getPaintingId());
    if (existing == null) {
        existing = new ArrayList<>();
        bidsByPainting.put(bid.getPaintingId(), existing);
    }
    existing.add(bid);

    // Sort the bids so that the highest is always first.
    // (Note that this only works because we made Bid implement Comparable)
    Collections.sort(existing);
}

// Now, at any time, you can get the highest bid for a painting by calling:
bidsByPainting.get(idYouCareAbout).get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class, introduce a method called

```
public Painting getPainting(String paintId)
```

- Iterate over each and every Painting object and check whether input arg paintIf matches with id with in each Painting object that you are iterating.
- If you find it return the same else either return a null or throw an exception.

If you want to develop an efficient way of doing this then i would say gor for map with key as id and value as painting object and you could just say

```
map.get(paintId)
```

to get the Paiting object.